# std::vector<int> vec[nx][ny];

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

I am familiar with the STL vectors. However, I would like to know which constructor is called and what it does when I initial a vector like the following:

`int nx=5;
 int ny=7;
 std::vector<int> myvec[nx][ny];`

update:
I compiled the code with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 but apparently it needs to be initialized with "const int" for some other compilers, so I rewrite it here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
std::vector<int> myvec[7][9];
return 0;
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you realize you're creating a 2D array of vectors (7x9), not a 2D vector.

Answer (score 3):

Will be called constructor 1 from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

In fact 63 times because you're creating 63 std::vectors, not one 2d vector.

It will compile. But it shouldn't. You have here a VLA. It's not valid C++ code.

Comment: This code is perfectly fine. It will create a 2d array of row = 7 and col = 9 of type vector<int>

Comment: Why do you think it's not valid c++ ? Are you talking about variable been used for declaring the array ? It you mean that, then it's actually compiler dependent and the code will compile in many compiler. Try gcc

Comment: @rj99999 That is a non standard extension. It isn't valid standard C++. It is something else.

Comment: Campilers allow to define VLAs because of backward compatibility. It is not a valid C++ code and you shouldn't write C++ code with VLA. It can be used only in C.

Comment: @rustyx: Yes there are. Since C99, introduced 17 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the variables `nx` and `ny` need to be `const` qualified as variable-length arrays are not standard C++.

But, when altering these variable to `const int`, this will declare a 2D array with 5 rows and 7 columns of default-initialised `std::vector<int>` instances, such that each element of the 2D array is initially an empty vector of `int` types.

Whilst that's what this does, that's not to say you should ever do something like this - a 2D C-style array of `std::vector` objects is a strange construct. If you want a fixed matrix where each element is a `std::vector` then use the following (for example) instead:

```
std::array<std::array<std::vector<int>, 7>, 5> mtx_vec;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.